# XSLT <xsl:when test="

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write an XSL document that tests if an outside parameter value is equal to a particular value in the input XML document.

The input XML document has multiple elements at the same level and I need to test each of the same level elements to see if they match the ID string. For example, there may be 5 elements called "WBScode" and each of them needs to be tested. If any element matches the value, the xsl when statement needs to be returned, if not, the otherwise statement is returned.

Below is the code I have, but what happens is it only tests the first element it finds in the document. How do I modify it to test each element of the document?

```
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="//Projects/Project/WBSs/WBS/WBSCode = $idStr">update</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>create</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is not consistent with XPath.  If your processor in fact exhibits that behavior then it is broken, but I'm inclined to suspect instead that it does not exhibit such behavior at all.  Thus, if in fact you have a *bona fide* problem then you have not conveyed it effectively.  In that case, present a [mcve] with which the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it only tests the first element it finds in the document

You are wrong about that. It tests every `WBSCode` element in turn and returns true when **any** one of them matches the value.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that just as you posted your reply. I was testing the document in Oxygen and was missing the outside parameter to test. When I manually tested by declaring a variable I found it worked. Thanks for the clarification!